# Is there a way of calling a Functional "Invoke" without using Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, actionscript, functional-programming

Is there any way, *without using Reflection*, of writing something along the lines of [OSteele's Functional Invoke](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/) in C#?

This means using it as in:

```
Action<T> MethodName = StaticUtil.Invoke<T>("MethodName", optionalCurriedArgs);
```

And then calling:

```
MethodName(objWithMethodName);
```

I know using a Lambda would do the trick.

What I mean, is using something along the lines of AS3's:

```
public static function invoke( selectedMethod : String, ... arguments ) : Function {
    var args : Array = arguments.slice();
    return function ( object : * ) : * {
        return object[ selectedMethod ].apply( object, args);
    };
}
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You could try a little harder to craft your question such that we have all that we need to answer it by staying right here.

Comment: Ok, will do. I thought it was clear enough already, it seems I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no obvious way in C# without using Reflection to call a function on a particular class. At best you might try `dynamic` and let it be resolved at runtime. You can try using a library like `FasterFlect` to solve your need.

Alternatively, if you want a built in method you can do

```
typeof(MyObject).InvokeMember(methodName
         ,BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance
         ,null
         ,myInstance
         ,new object[]{parameter1,parameter2})
```

I would be lying to you if I said it wasn't reflection though. The CLR wasn't designed for you to invoke methods dynamically like javascript. This was a conscious decision to make a high performance method call. If you need to pass functions around use Delegates. If your method needs variable argument support you can use overloads, or `params`. If you need to call methods dynamically via strings:
use `Dictionary<string,DelegateType>` or if you know you have a few methods and need absolute speed use a `List<Tuple<string,DelegateType>>`.  If you have many types that all respond to a message use `Interfaces`. If the classes aren't your own, or they are specialized for primitives try `dynamic`.

C# is a well designed language written for standard coding practices. There are lots of options. If you really need to they give you the tools to look up members and invoke them. Reflection is slow because the CLR was designed to be SAFE first. If you find yourself needing lots of reflection dynamic invocation you might want to reconsider your design choices. If you still can find no other way you can still use caching and `Delegates` to make that fast. `dynamic` is entirely done with clever caching and delegates, and dynamic in the best cases is nearly as fast as native code.

In theory, you can create a pattern like `CallSite<T>` in the DLR to fast cache a particular call site. I do something similar in a dynamic proxy I wrote to get around the fact that there is no way to create a function pointer to an open generic method. (e.g. I wanted to have a `mydelegate.Invoke<T>(T arg)` ).